# Java thread safety of setting a reference to an object

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm wondering if the following class is thread safe:

```
class Example {

private Thing thing;

public setThing(Thing thing) {
    this.thing = thing;
    }

public use() {
    thing.function();
    }
}
```

Specifically, what happens if one thread calls setThing while another thread is in Thing::function via Example::use?

For example:

```
Example example = new Example();
example.setThing(new Thing());

createThread(example);  // create first thread
createThread(example);  // create second thread
```

---

```
//Thread1
while(1) {
  example.use();
}
```

---

```
//Thread2
while(1) {
    sleep(3600000); //yes, i know to use a scheduled thread executor
    setThing(new Thing());
}
```

Specifically, I want to know, when setThing is called while use() is executing, will it continue with the old object successfully, or could updating the reference to the object somehow cause a problem.

Comment: The second thread might see the new value, or not. If it does see it, it may not be fully constructed. Depends how thread safe `Thing` is.

Comment: `thing` will never be null in your example since variable assignments are atomic in Java (expect for long and double). However, thread1 may still use an older object of Thing after thread2 has set it to a new value. Declare thing as `volatile ` to avoid this. thread1 will always complete the execution of the `function()` method using the same Thing-Object

Comment: @rollback, you answered specifically what I was asking, feel free to make it an answer. I'll update my question, since you put into good words what I couldn't express. Any documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 points when reasoning about thread safety of a particulcar class :

1. Visibility of shared state between threads.
2. Safety (preserving class invariants) when class object is used by multiple threads through class methods.

Shared state of `Example` class consists only from one `Thing` object.

1. The class isn't thread safe from visibility perspective. Result of `setThing` by one thread isn't seen by other threads so they can work with stale data. NPE is also acceptable cause initial value of `thing` during class initialization is `null`.
2. It's not possible to say whether it's safe to access `Thing` class through `use` method without its source code. However `Example` invokes `use` method without any synchronization so it should be, otherwise `Example` isn't thread safe.

As a result `Example` isn't thread safe. To fix point 1 you can either add `volatile` to `thing` field if you really need setter or mark it as final and initialize in constructor. The easiest way to ensure that 2 is met is to mark `use` as `synchronized`. If you mark `setThing` with `synchronized` as well you don't need `volatile` anymore. However there lots of other sophisticated techniques to meet point 2. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) great book describes everything written here in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is sharing resources and the thread is not synchronized, then the they will collide and several scenarios can occur including overwriting data computed by another thread and stored in a shared variable.

If the method has only local variables, then you can use the method by mutliple threads without worring about racing. However, usually non-helper classes manipulate member variables in their methods, therefore it's recommended to make methods synchronized or if you know exactly where the problem might occur, then lock (also called synchronize) a subscope of a method with a `final` lock/object.